# inserting multiple records and check if a row has no records

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Basically, I have a form which has 5 rows.

Like this:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
<p><label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name[]"  />
<label>email</label>
<input type="text" name="email[]"   />
</p>
<p><label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name[]"  />
<label>email</label>
<input type="text" name="email[]"   />
</p>
<p><label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name[]"  />
<label>email</label>
<input type="text" name="email[]"  />
</p>
<p><label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name[]"  />
<label>email</label>
<input type="text" name="email[]"  />
</p>
<p><label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name[]"  />
<label>email</label>
<input type="text" name="email[]"  />
</p>
<input name="Submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

This is my process.php

```
<?php
// connect to the database
include('db.php');


$name = count($_POST['name']);
$email = count($_POST['email']);

if ($name > 0 && $name == $email) {
    $insertArr = array();
    for ($i=0; $i<$name; $i++) {
        $insertArr[] = "('" . $_POST['name'][$i] . "', '" . $_POST['email'][$i] . "')";
    }
}



$sql = "INSERT INTO comments(name, email) VALUES " . implode(',', $insertArr) ;
$qry = $conn->prepare ($sql);
$qry->execute($insertArr);



echo("<pre>\n");
print_r($_POST);
echo("</pre>\n");


?>
```

But if the user has just input 4 records the 5th row does not have value but they're being saved to the database. I want to check if the user has 5 inputs if not then I have to ignore the null and save only the fields that have inputs. Does anyone know how to do this? I would gladly appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: In for loop check $_POST['name'][$i] IS null before adding in to your $insertArr[] array.

Comment: You should look into prepared statements. Looks like you're using PDO? Then you could bind the values and execute them in the loop instead of building an insert string, which is VERY vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of these two lines:

```
$name = count($_POST['name']);
$email = count($_POST['email']);
```

Replace with:

```
$name=0;$email=0;
foreach($_POST['name'] as $post_name)
{
    ($post_name!=='')?$name++:''; //checks for empty values and increments accordingly
}

foreach($_POST['email'] as $post_email)
{
    ($post_email!=='')?$email++:'';
}
echo 'name counted = '.$name.'<br>';
echo 'email counted = '.$email.'<br>';
```

Also, I added this bit to your code:

```
if($_POST['name'][$i]!='' || $_POST['email'][$i]!='') //This checks if there is value in name or email of that index, if not it won't enter any blank.
{
 $insertArr[] = "('" . $_POST['name'][$i] . "', '" . $_POST['email'][$i] . "')";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account if a user fills out the same amount of emails/names but isn't using the same paragraphs. Could end up inserting the wrong combinations.

Comment: @NewInTheBusiness : Nope, won't result in wrong combinations although it will leave a blank in the adjacent cell but this is assuming the fact that the OP wants `at least either` the `name` or `email` to be entered into the database.

Comment: Didn't see your last bit of code, my mistake. Yeah, maybe you're right he wants only email saved for instance, even though he's a bit vague on that point.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use array_filter on the name array to remove all empty values.

```
$names = array_filter($_POST['name']);
$emails = $_POST['email'];
```

Then you remove the ones that don't have a corresponding match from both arrays so you only insert when both email and name are entered.

```
   $nr = 0;
   foreach ($emails as $e) {
      if (!$names[$nr] || empty($emails[$nr)) unset($emails[$nr]);   
      $nr++;  
   }
```

Cleaning up array keys

```
$names = array_values($names);
$emails = array_values($emails);
$i = 0;
foreach ($names as $n) {
   $insertArr[] = "('" . $n . "', '" . $emails[$i] . "')";
   $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're trying to achieve but if it will always be 5 posts in the future you could solve it like this:

```
    $name = $_POST['name0'];
    $email = $_POST['email0'];
    if ((!empty($name))&&(!empty($email))) {
    $mysqli->query("YOUR_SQL_COMMAND");
    echo '<your text>';
    }
    $name = $_POST['name1'];
    $email = $_POST['email1'];
    if ((!empty($name))&&(!empty($email))) {
    $mysqli->query("YOUR_SQL_COMMAND");
    echo '<your text>';
    } // and so on
```

And change the HTML to following:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
<p><label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name0"  />
<label>email</label>
<input type="text" name="email0"   />
</p>
<p><label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name1"  />
<label>email</label>
<input type="text" name="email1"   />
</p>
<p><label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name2"  />
<label>email</label>
<input type="text" name="email2"  />
</p>
<p><label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name3"  />
<label>email</label>
<input type="text" name="email3"  />
</p>
<p><label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name4"  />
<label>email</label>
<input type="text" name="email4"  />
</p>
<input name="Submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```